# jquery cycle plugin with thumbnails scrollable to left or right onclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I am trying to integrate jquery image slider. But I need to slide the thumbnails to left and right also(like http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/). I could create thumbnails. But I couldn't find any option to slide the thumbnails. Is there any option in cycle plugin. How can I do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cycle Plugin does not offer this as default.
You can achieve what you're after but it means you'll have to write something up.

I would recommend you using something which can offer what you're after by default, have a look at Scrollable: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html

It's really easy to use and you can do anything with it using their API.

Comment: Is there any other plugin which offers thumbnail scrolling and main image scrolling??

Comment: I think would do exactly what you need: [http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/#example-4](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/#example-4) The only thing you will need to do is add the thumbnails.

Comment: I was checking the ad-gallery plugin for the image slideshow. But it seems there is no thumbnail creation on the fly in this plugin. I need a plugin where I can create thumbnails on the fly like cycle plugin. Also i had a look at galleria plugin and there it seems we need to use the themes to work it.

Answer (score 1):

See if it can help...

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Comment: i checked the options of cycle plugin. But it seems there is no option like that for thumbnails..